# Find coupon creator on payment completion in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm developing a plugin.

I need to find out when any `coupon` issued by a specific `user_id` used in any `order` on payment completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve coupons used by an order using `get_coupons()` method on `WC_Order` instance:

```php
$coupons = $order->get_coupons();
```

If you need only coupon codes just call `get_coupon_codes()`. It returns an array of strings:

```php
$coupon_codes = $order->get_coupon_codes();
```

Now if you want to check it on order payment you WooCommerce hooks:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'my_payment_completion_hook' );

function aac_wc_payment_complete_hook( $order_id ) {
    $order        = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $used_coupons = $order->get_coupon_codes();
    if ( count( $used_coupons ) ) {
        $coupon       = new WC_coupon( $used_coupons[0] );
        $post         = get_post( $coupon->id );
        $user_id = $post->post_author;
        if ( $user_id == 100) {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```